# Publishing to npm with --access public not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm attempting to publish a new scoped package to NPM running the command `npm publish --access public` like this:

```
    ole@mki:~/cli$ npm publish --access public
    npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
    npm ERR! code E403
    npm ERR! Forbidden : @superflycss/cli

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2018-03-07T23_28_40_883Z-debug.log
```

I am logged in to NPM, and recently published an update to another package, so not sure why a new package is giving me issues?

Comment: so you are the one using my name... :D - sorry for the "not useful" comment

Comment: but the error tells that you have a problem with your authentication. Maybe your ssh key? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 (you need to have access rights to that `@superflycss/cli`

Comment: I'm using the name but the project is open source so contributions welcome :).  It should work without an SSH key as I have just published an update to another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I ran `npm addUser` with a user name that is different from my current NPM username.  So NPM happily accepted the new one and sent me an email to confirm the new one.  Meanwhile I thought I was authenticated.

So 1.0.0 is published!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli