# Issue running npm publish --access public (E403)

Tags: javascript, json, npm, command-line-interface, npm-publish

I'm trying to publish a scoped package to npm, but I keep getting this error on the CLI:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@username%2fdynamic-ui-elements - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cutler/.npm/_logs/2022-05-16T23_08_36_735Z-debug.log
```

I have looked [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163018/publishing-to-npm-with-access-public-not-working) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718308/npm-err-403-403-forbidden-npm-publish) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550967/error-403-forbidden-account-disabled-when-publishing-npm-package) [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103353/how-do-i-publish-an-npm-package-with-a-two-factor-authentication-error) [trying](https://github.com/semantic-release/npm/issues/209) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950544/npm-publish-registry-403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-publish) [solve](https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/npm-publish-error-message/788/6) the issue, but none of the suggestions I've seen have worked.

- I am logged in on the CLI
- My npm email is verified
- there is no other package with the same name, as I'm publishing this scoped to my username and I've never published any other packages
- I've tried the command as `npm publish --access public` as well as `npm publish --access=public`
- 2FA is enabled

Regarding the 2FA, I've tried both with and without "Require two-factor authentication for write actions" checked.  When it IS checked, instead of the above error, I get prompted for a one-time password, but upon entering the generated code from my google authenticator app, I get the E403 again.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958612/publish-to-npm-not-working-even-though-all-credentials-are-met) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941393/problem-with-two-factor-atuhentication-in-npm) questions mirror my own, but neither has been answered.  Am I using the authenticator wrong?  Is there a setting I'm missing?

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "@username/dynamic-ui-elements",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Some dynamic UI elements to transform your HTML",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "webpack serve --open"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/CutlerSheridan/dynamic-ui-elements.git"
    },
    "author": "Cutler Sheridan <cutler.sheridan@gmail.com>",
    "license": "ISC",
    "files": [
        "src/dynamicUi.js",
        "README.md"
    ],
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/CutlerSheridan/dynamic-ui-elements/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/CutlerSheridan/dynamic-ui-elements#readme",
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.72.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can assure me that you intentionally replaced `@username` under `"name"` in `package.json` with your real username?

Comment: Jesus.  This was the problem.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm so glad you got it fixed. Good thing I decided to point it out, I just thought you replaced it on purpose . Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite reading that `package.json` 100 times, the problem was that I had not changed the auto-generated `"name": "@username/dynamic-ui-elements"` to be my real username.